# Confusion in using Super in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, python-2.x

I am getting an error for the program:

```
 class TennisPlayer():
    def __init__(self, rank):
        self.rank = rank
    def slogan(self):
        print("What Slogan!")

class GrandSlamWinner(TennisPlayer):
    def __init__(self, rank=0, slams=0):
        TennisPlayer.__init__(self, rank)
        self.slams = slams
    def slogan(self):
        super(GrandSlamWinner, self).slogan()
        print("This: Are you serious!!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mcenroe = GrandSlamWinner(1,7)
    print(mcenroe.slams)
    mcenroe.slogan()
```

I Get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subclassing.py", line 18, in <module>
    mcenroe.slogan()
  File "subclassing.py", line 12, in slogan
    super(GrandSlamWinner, self).slogan()
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

So, how are we supposed to override superclass methods in Python?

Also, is there any standard way to do modify or add to superclasses while subclassing, like a set a conventions -- e.g. nitialize superclass inside the subclass's init function?

Cheers!

Comment: Presumably you’re using Python 2.x, where super doesn’t work with old-style classes. Upgrade to 3.x. And Google your error messages.

Comment: You forgot to inherit from `object` in `TennisPlayer`.

Comment: @user2357112 i read that was implicit.

Comment: @Rafael  It is, but only in Python 3.

Comment: @wim oh! i though python 2 vs python 3 debate was just about small things like print. Got to study more.

Comment: Or stop using Python 2. It’s unsupported as of 2020.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, one trouble I have is that a lot of code is in python 2. And setting it up in python 3 takes effort.